# Ajax not getting latest entry from sql but posting correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with getting my latest entry with ajax, It posts to the database correctly but it won´t load my latest entry. I post:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/AddEmployee",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "companyId": companyId, "name": name, "role": role, "desc": desc, "email": email, "phone": phone, "sortOrder": sortOrder }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (!response.success) {
                        $("#loaderAddemployee").text(response.errors);
                    $("#loaderAddemployee").css("display", "none");
                }
                    else {

                        alert("resource added");
```

After my post I check database and I can see the entry there, so far so good.

With jquery I try to get my posts when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        GetEmployees();
```

The function get reached:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/home/GetEmployees?companyId=" + companyId,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "companyId": companyId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var employee = response;
            var count = 0;
            alert(employee.length);
```

I have added the `alert(employee.length); to see how many entries there are in my database, and it gets called every time I refresh my browser, indicating that the function gets reached and the response is successfull. Here is the problem. When I start debugging the project the alert displays the correct number (number of entries in my table), but if I now post a new entry it correctly gets added to my database but when I refresh the alert still display the number of entries I had before.

For example:
I debug my project in visual studio, the number of entries in my database are 5. The alert shows 5.
I make a post and refresh the page, the alert still shows 5. (I can see the post in my sql database).
I stop debug mode and start it again, now my alert shows 6.

So it only updates my "get" request once, when I start the project from visual studio. For obvious reasons I wish my data to get updated on every browser refresh.

Any ideas as to what is happening here?
It is an mvc project if that has any bearing on the subject.

Comment: Disable cache in your browser and try again. It might be an issue with the caching of the browser.

Comment: Try jQuery.ajax() setting `cache: false`

Comment: Tried but still no success :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is caching issue, try to add timestamp to your GET request.